# set tooltip for textfield using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm creating a new pdf using pdfbox, and want to set tooltip for pdtextfield on mouse hover.

On the official doc there is getToolTip() method but i didn't found a set method.

here is the expected output:

[image: here is the expected output]

Comment: Which version of PDFBox are you using? So you do also create the textfield? Show us some code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that you create the PDF from scratch so you do also create the textfield (and don't want to add a tooltip to an existing textfield).
Since you didn't post code nor mention the PdfBox version you are using I have nothing to go on, but in general you could do it like this (The TU key is the attribute used in acrobat as a tooltip and it is called alternate field name):

```
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();

    PDTextField textbox = new PDTextField(doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm());
    textbox.setAlternateFieldName("Your tooltip text");
    textbox.set...  //(set all the other attributes)
```

This code assumes that you are using PdfBox in version 2.X. In 1.8.X you have to do a bit more...

Comment: Strictly speaking **TU** is specified as *an alternative field name that shall be used in place of the actual field name wherever the field shall be identified in the user interface*, so one should not use it for *arbitrary* texts to appear in tooltips, in particular as explicit examples are *error or status messages referring to the field*. Thus, the **TU** should never be the same for different fields and should make sense as identifiers. An error message like "The field 'Please insert a valid email address' must not be empty" unlikely is what you want to read in your UI...

Comment: Yeah I know but *dobe abuses the field for this. So it is not bad to add a hint in the jdoc of the method. We wouldn't want to rename the method from `setAlternateFieldName` to `setQuickInfo` / `setTooltip` ;-)